# Upgrading MySQL 5.5 to 5.7 on Plesk-managed Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, plesk

I'm trying to upgrade MySQL on my Plesk-managed Virtual Server (Ubuntu 14.4) from version 5.5 to 5.7.

On the Plesk support sites and on the Internet I found the same sequence of steps. It goes like:

```
(1) wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_XYZ_all.deb
(2) sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_XYZ_all.deb
(3) sudo apt-get update
(4) sudo apt-get install mysql-server
(5) mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
```

I've done that, however in step 4 I get the following message:

```
mysql-server is already the newest version.
```

Nothing gets installed, I'm still on 5.5.

What am I doing wrong here? I have a whole bunch of databases for different websites - what would happen if I told Plesk to desinstall and reinstall mysql, running line (5) above after that?

Comment: Do you have any more MySQL repositories configured in apt? Why do you replace the version with "XYZ", just list the complete package. Also you do know that Ubuntu 14.04 is EOL since May, unless you pay for extended support?

Comment: Questions involving management panels like plesk are off topic; ubunt 14.04 is end of life, making the question off topic as well. Upgrade to a current distribution, and you will get a newer MySQL version as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - guess I'll have to move to a different server then. Sorry for being off-topic ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 is EOL and no longer supported. Move up to a later version such as 18.04 LTS which is supported until 2023. The repos for Bionic Beaver will have MySQL 5.7 available so that you can just install it via `apt`.

Before doing any of this, make sure to dump your databases before doing anything in case something goes awry.

You can also install MySQL 5.7 from Percona. As `root`:

```
wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb

dpkg -i percona-release_latest.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb

apt-get update

apt-get install percona-server-server-5.7 percona-server-client-5.7 percona-server-common-5.7
```

Whether you install it from the Ubuntu repos or the Percona repos, you can then import the databases that you dumped after configuring the new installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted my hoster in the meantime and they strongly discouraged upgrading MySQL at all. Together with 14.4 being EOL, they also suggested migration to a newer server, which is what we'll do.